# recursive map dependent of two vectors

Tags: r

Basically;

```
 a<-c(1,2,1,2)
 b<-c(1,2,3,4)
```

I seek a function that returns a vector c with c[n]=b[n]+b[n-1] if a[n] even or b[n]+2b[n-1] otherwise.

Is there anything easier than a brute force for-loop? Some sort of advanced "Reduce" or equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x <- c(0, b[-length(b)]) # shifted b, 0 for first element
c <- ifelse((a %% 2) == 0, b + x, b + 2*x)
```

Be careful, length of a should be equal to length of b.